# Errors importing Theano in Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, theano

I have a project set up in PyCharm that uses imports from Theano.
I believe I have completed all the steps in the Theano installation guide and have included the necessary libraries in the Project Interpreter (Theano 0.7.0, numpy 1.9.2, and scipu 0.14.0, among others).

Yet, when compiling I get the following errors:

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe -shared -g -march=ivybridge -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mno-movbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mno-abm -mno-lwp -mno-fma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mno-bmi -mno-bmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mno-avx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mno-lzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mno-clflushopt -mno-xsavec -mno-xsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=8192 -mtune=ivybridge -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m32 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -Ic:\theano-master\theano\gof -o C:\Users\jlhag_000\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-32\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\jlhag_000\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27 -lpython27
===============================
Traceback (most recent call last):
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
  File "C:/Users/jlhag_000/PycharmProjects/TheanoPractice/DBN.py", line 9, in <module>
C:\Python27\libs/python27.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
    import theano
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>

    from theano.compile import (
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 19, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\compile\mode.py", line 10, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\gof\vm.py", line 666, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 126, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "c:\theano-master\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2059, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
. 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Would appreciate it if someone can point out what else I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure you kept everything of the same bit-ed-ness. i.e. is everything you installed compiled for x86 (32 bit) or all for x64 (64 bit)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I installed all the 64-bit dlls. Also made sure that all installations were for Python 2.7. I will try again today, this time compiling everything from source instead of relying on the precompiled libraries. Will update with the outcomes. If that doesn't work, I'll try again with the 32-bit releases.

Comment: I use Anaconda on Windows (though I don't use a GPU on Windows) and all I have to do beyond installing Anaconda and the GitHub version of Theano is `conda install mingw libpython`

Comment: If you are using TDM GCC you might need to recompile libpython.a. I was able to solve the above error by following the instructions on rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano - loosely modified to rather use the gendef and dlltool that are bundled with TDM GCC.